# as3 | How to write an onComplete code without using a function

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

this is an easy question but I can't seem to get it right.

Instead of writing this (=an onComplete function):

```
Tweener.addTween(resultsIntro, {alpha:0, time:0.5, transition:"easeIn", onComplete:func});

function func() {
    myResults.removeChild(resultsIntro);
}
```

I want to write something like this (and it is not working because I don't know how to write it right):

```
Tweener.addTween(resultsIntro, {alpha:0, time:0.5, transition:"easeIn",
                 onComplete:(myResults.removeChild(resultsIntro);)});
```

because I don't need this function - how can I write the onComplete code in the same place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Tweener.addTween(resultsIntro, {alpha:0, time:0.5, transition:"easeIn",
             onComplete:function() { myResults.removeChild(resultsIntro); });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try anonymous function(){}.
This technique is similar to JavaScript closures.